# AyncTask stops if screen rotates

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have read many questions regarding this only but unable to find a correct solution...The issue is that i have created a dummy `AsyncTask` and while it is running , i rotate the screen and the AsyncTask stops abruptly.

So i am unable to save its state such that when the screen rotates it resumes from that state only

I can't use this solution as i am not using Fragment :-
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Also, i don't want any solution saying that lock your screen orientation while the Async is running

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{
      //Some Code
      ProgressDialog progressDialog; // Global Variable
      //OnCreateMethod Here
      //.......
       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        DummyTask dt = new DummyTask();
        dt.execute();
      }
      private class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore) {
      try{
          Thread.sleep(3000);
      }
      catch(Exception e){}
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
      if (progressDialog!=null) {
    pd.dismiss();


     }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

Comment: use an IntentService then... ! & use a Messenger to update the UI stuff.

Comment: I've used AsyncTasks that don't stop during rotation... could you show the code you're running in the AsyncTask? You're probably referencing an object that's getting destroyed because of the rotation...

Comment: It is just a simple async task and there is a progress bar and in the do in backgroud method i run a thread for 3 seconds and during that time i rotate my screen and the app crashes. Obviously i get a null pointer exception on the progress bar reference but even if i remove that progress bar then also the asnc task stops because i have a Toast in the post execute which should be shown when the thread awake but it doesn't when i rotate the screen

Comment: Sounds strange to me. Usually this is problem when using ProgressBar as the Dialog is not maintained, but the AsyncTask itself should not be bothered by orientation changes as far as I know. If you do UI operations in the background part then that should be refactored to only run in onPostExecute.

Comment: Let the Toast use context.getApplicationContext(), that should work then

Comment: Dude the point is the async stops on orientation change. Try it yourself. Toast is just an example to check whether it is working or not. Uploaded the code

Comment: The code you're posting should actually throw an Exception. The ProgressDialog gets dismissed even though it doesn't have a living parent, if I recall it correctly, so your AsyncTask never makes it to the Toast. In my project I simply re-created the progress dialog if the task was still alive...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to work with `AsyncTask` and configuration changes. I'd say you basically have two options:

1. When a configuration change is detected (ie. your `Activity` goes through the destroy lifecycle events) you cancel your `AsyncTask` and restarts them when the new `Activity` gets created
2. You can detach and attach it using retain configuration

See CommonsWare example of #2 here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java

Comment: Cancelling it and Rrestarting it again is really not an option because i will be running services with many parameters and restarting them will take up much time. Will definitely check out the links

Comment: Then have a look at that second option, it will keep the tasks running. But depending on what you need to do I would suggest you to use a `Service` instead and **in that service** use `AsyncTask` to do your work.

Comment: I am really not getting the service things. I have Http post request services being called in all the Async Task i use. This service and your `Service` are the same thing? Could you post an example because i am not getting this " in that Service use AsyncTask"

Comment: Please see my other answer for how to use a Service.

Comment: @RahulGupta - Did you get it to work? If so, please select this answer.

Comment: It is a good answer but i didn't used it., I used fragment aand in that a global async task and overrided its preexecute and other methods in main class using an interface

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, using a `Service` can be a better implementation:

```
public class DownloaderService extends Service {

    private LongRunningAsyncTask task = null;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // Start task
        task = new LongRunningAsyncTask();
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

    }

}
```

And you can start your `Service` from your `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloaderService.class);    
startService(intent);
```

You can even call startService multiple times and it will always go to the same `DownloaderService` instance. So make sure your not starting `AsyncTask` if one is already running. And one way to communicate with any `Activity` you can use broadcasts.

Also, even if you're not using a `Service` make sure you understand how different Android versions executes `AsyncTask`. Please read up on this:

- http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html